# R - individual categorical plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, sequence, data-visualization

I would simply like to represent a sequence of categorical states with different colours.

This kind of plot is also known as `individual sequence plot` (`TraMineR`).

I would like to use `ggplot2`.

My data simply look like this

```
> head(dta)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 id
1  b  a  e  d  c  1
2  d  b  a  e  c  2
3  b  c  a  e  d  3
4  c  b  a  e  d  4
5  b  c  e  a  d  5
```

with the `personal id` in the last column.

The plot looks like this.

[image]

Each `letters` (states) is represented by a colour. Basically, this plot visualise the successive states for each individual.

Blue is `a`, Red is `b`, Purple is `c`, Yellow is `d` and Brown is `e`.

Any idea how I could do this with `ggplot2`?

```
dta = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "e"), class = "factor"), V4 =  structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
V5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("c", "d"
), class = "factor"), id = 1:5), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

**what I tried so far**

```
nr = nrow(dta3)
nc = ncol(dta3)

# space 
m = 0.8
n = 1 # do not touch this one 

plot(0, xlim = c(1,nc*n), ylim = c(1, nr), type = 'n', axes = F, ylab = 'individual sequences', xlab = 'Time')

axis(1, at = c(1:nc*m), labels = c(1:nc))
axis(2, at = c(1:nr), labels = c(1:nr) )

for(i in 1:nc){
  points(x = rep(i*m,nr) , y = 1:nr, col = dta3[,i], pch = 15) 
}
```

But it is not with `ggplot2` and not very satisfying.

[image]

Comment: Anything you've already tried?

Comment: No actually - I have no idea where to begin

Comment: I think the word you need to search for is 'heatmap' /ggplot2.

Comment: But it is actually not a heatmap and it involve not calculation.

Comment: The general recipe here is melt your data, and then use geom_tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

m_dta <- melt(dta,id.var="id")
m_dta

p1 <- ggplot(m_dta,aes(x=variable,y=id,fill=value))+
  geom_tile()
p1
```

[image]